# How to display Custom Taskpane in Office 2013?

Tags: vsto, add-in, excel-2013, office-addins, office-2013

I have developed an Excel Addin using VSTO 4.0. 
There is a Custom taskpane that contains various controls to perform functions.
the Custom Taskpane works fine with office 2010 and is displayed on left.
but When i install the addin for office 2013 on Windows 8.1 it does not apear at all?

Below is the code snippet im using to display the taskpane;

```
var taskPaneProcessMapView = new TaskPanes.taskpaneProcessMap().GetInstance();
        this.TaskPaneProcessMap = Globals.ThinkReliabilityAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneProcessMapView, "Process Map");
        this.TaskPaneProcessMap.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

> this.TaskPaneProcessMap.Visible = false;

May be you need to set the Visible property to true?

Anyway, is your add-in enabled? Did you have a chance to check out the COM add-ins list in Excel? Is it listed in the Inactive add-ins list?

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again. See [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: the Addin is enabled. and i set the visible to true when it is required. it shows the Ribbon menu. but it does not show the taskpane. i have button on ribbon clicking on that button displays the task pane. it works on office 2010 but does nothing on 2013 . even no exception is logged.

im not sure but i guess the problem is due to the fact that Office 2010 is MDI where multiple workbooks can be opened in single excel instance. and in case of 2013 the Office is SDI where every new workbook opens a new excel instance.